# Armature out of place in object mode but not in edit mode...or almost

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, transforms

for some reason that I don't understand my armature seems to be out of place in object mode,but not in edit mode and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone helps me ? I've attached 2 pictures to show you.

[image: armature in object mode]
[image: armature in edit mode]

Comment: could you please provide your .blend file to be able to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you accidentally moved the armature or bones in pose mode? You could try switching to pose mode

- <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset all rotation,
- <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to reset all translation,
- <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to reset all scale.